# org.w3c.dom.Node with Android version less than 2.2

Tags: java, android, xml, w3c

getTextContent() is not a recognized function.  getNodeValue() works fine for strings, but anytime I try to parse a number using getNodeValue(), it returns null!

How can I parse a Long from XML using this class?

Answer (score 6):

The root cause of this is that the `getTextContent()` method is a W3C DOM Level 3 method; see the [changes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/changes.html) section of the DOM level 3 core spec.

> *The Node interface has two new attributes, Node.baseURI and Node.textContent.* ...

and `getTextContent()` is the getter for the new attribute.

(Presumably, older versions of Android don't implement the DOM level 3 APIs.)

The behavior of `getTextContent()` is a bit complicated in the general case; see the spec for the [textContext attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent).  In the simple case where the target node is an Element with (only) text contents, `node.getTextContext()` is the same as `node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to navigate down to the text node. For instance, with something like this:

```
<val>10000</val>
```

the parsed XML tree has an Element node for the  tag which, in turn, has a child Text node for the "10000". A typical idiom is

```
valNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

If as you say "getNodeValue() works fine for strings", then nothing should prevent from doing the:

```
Long l = Long.getLong(node.getNodeValue());
```

Note, `getNodeValue()` will always return a `String` that should be then manually converted to a numerical type.

Also - are you sure you are parsing a right node (the one that holds the needed long value)?