# How can i get element text in node in Java?

Tags: java

I am new to Android Development,and want to parse the XML and bind to Google MapView.
However, i cannot read the Text between element.

The XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>
    <table name="clinicaddress">
        <row>
            <GeoPoint>22.3852860,113.9664120</GeoPoint>
        </row>
        <row>
            <GeoPoint>22.336950,114.1578720</GeoPoint>
        </row>
    </table>
```

The Code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

try {
            inputStream = assetManager.open("clinics.xml");
            String xmlRecords = readTextFile(inputStream);
            //Log.e("Clinics XML", xmlRecords);

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);

            doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();

            NodeList listOfClinics = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");
            Log.e("listOfClinics Length" , String.valueOf(listOfClinics.getLength()));

            //Loop the XML

            for (int x = 0; x < listOfClinics.getLength(); x++) {
                Node ClinicNode = listOfClinics.item(x);
                NodeList ClinicInfo = ClinicNode.getChildNodes();
                for (int y = 0; y < ClinicInfo.getLength(); y++) {
                    Node info = ClinicInfo.item(y);
                    Log.e(info.getNodeName() , info.getNodeValue()); //<--Error on info.getNodeValue()
                }
}
            //End Loop XML
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
```

So, what wrong with getNodeValue()???

[image]

And one more question, how can i set the Eclipse like Visual Studio,
If any error, it will break to the line on source line file, instead of just print out the stack message on debug windows.

**UPDATED 1.**
I found this post:
org.w3c.dom.Node with Android version less than 2.2
[org.w3c.dom.Node with Android version less than 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771119/org-w3c-dom-node-with-android-version-less-than-2-2)

> node.getTextContext() is the same as
>   node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().

However, i try this, it is goes error too.

Comment: To break on exceptions you have to select Run->Add Java Exception Breakpoint. You can then choose to break on every exception or specific ones.

Comment: I search in SOF, someone said set "Throwable" and checked caught and uncaught, but the result still not expect like Visualstudio..

Comment: You could perhaps post this as a separate question with a test case and expected result. AFAIK Eclipse should break on every checked/unchecked exception if you catch Throwable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, i get this works.

I use `info.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()`

```
        for (int y = 0; y < ClinicInfo.getLength(); y++) {
            Node info = ClinicInfo.item(y);
            if (info.hasChildNodes()) {
                Log.e(info.getNodeName(), info.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }
        }
```

Line 3 is important, i Log the hasChildNodes() and watch in LogCat, don't know why it contains a node named "#text" and no childnodes (which is false on logcat).

But i believe my XML is correct format.
After Google, found many explanation.
[https://www.google.com/search?q=xml+%23text](https://www.google.com/search?q=xml%20#text)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Use the getTextContent() method.

```
node.getTextContent()
```

The getTextContent() method returns the text of all of the nested tags.

Comment: but i cannot find it, see the screenshot i updated. I stay long time on .NET world and new to Java. I search in SOF, it seem i have to use JDOM namespace, but it not exist on the Android API.

Comment: What jar is the Node implementation in?  My JDK 1.6 has that method on implementors of Node.

Comment: it probabbly depends on a version, I use 1.7 java but the getTextContent method is not available anymore

Answer (score 2):

Text are just children of the node.
you need to loop over all the children of the GeoPoint Node, check the node type to be Node.TEXT_NODE and concatenate the texts